# Como mostrar un json en angular?

Tags: json, angular

Hola necesito mostrar un json en angular, alguien me puede ayudar, esta es un trozo del json, despues de "COMMAND WORD" todo sigue siendo lo mismo hasta el final

```
[ { "impianto": { "anagrafica": { "Chiave": "asfdasdfasdf", "Name": "sadfasdfasdf", "Modello": "asdfasf" }, "streams": { "1": { "data": { "COMMAND WORD": { "value": 1, "unMis": "" },
```

Answer (score 1):

¿A qué te refieres con mostrar? La pregunta es muy ambigua
Si te refieres a imprimir el JSON con formato tal cual en tu HTML puedes usar https://highlightjs.org/usage/

Si tienes el JSON y quieres mostrar su contenido en el html puedes usar el pipe json
https://angular.io/api/common/JsonPipe

Si quieres mostrar alguna propiedad en específico puedes desestructurar el objeto

```
component.ts

let foo =[ { "impianto": {...}];

component.html
<div> {{ foo[0].streams.1}}</div>
```